# serving geoserver trough nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express, openlayers, geoserver

Hi I am developing a map application with nodejs with express,I use googlemap as base layer and some others layers served by geoserver as wms, my application run on port 3000, while geoserver is on 8080, then as far I access my application  in localhost it works, if access it from another computer, I do not get the map, I would like to know, what I should do for making my application available from others computers, have I to set apache or express to redirect the request to geoserver?

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with node, express, geoserver or etc. It is fully to do with lack of understanding of the web works. Check what is public and local IP address as well how to make thing accessible from local computer from the web (static IP + port forwarding).

Comment: ok thanks can you suggest me something to read? Any way at the moment I am working on my personal network at my home

Comment: It is very wide and general topic, google is very rich with topics for queries like: "port forwarding" "what is static ip" and so on.